# TypeScript 2.1 Feature of Implicit Import Not Working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was very excited about the latest TypeScript 2.1.4 release in that a big factor in convincing my team to use TS is the ability to import an installed module without having to find or create type definitions for it, which [implicit any imports provide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#untyped-imports). For some reason, however, this doesn't seem to be working as advertised, as I still get error messages telling me that a module cannot be found. When I install types for my module (React in this case) it works just fine.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my_app_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --colors --port 8282"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.9",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*"
  ]
}
```

And a sample .tsx file for a React component that replicates this issue:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface HelloProps { compiler: string; framework: string; }

export const Hello = (props: HelloProps) => {
    return <h1>Hello from {props.compiler} and {this.props.framework}!</h1>
};
```

I also went ahead and created another project replicating this issue and uploaded it to [BitBucket for anyone interested](https://Alex-ayala@bitbucket.org/Alex-ayala/ts_importany_issue.git). Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this turns out to be an issue with TypeScript itself, I'll make sure to create an Issue on the Github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like implicit import does not always work. When I fixed your `package.json` (removed trailing comma in `scripts`) and `tsconfig.json` (added `bin` to `exclude`), I'm getting these errors with typescript 2.1.4:

```
src/greeter.tsx(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-modal'.
src/greeter.tsx(19,26): error TS2339: Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'Greeter'.
```

I think I khow the explanation for the first one. In `package.json` for `react-modal`, the `main` property is

```
"main": "./lib/index",
```

but the actual file has `.js` extension, that is, it's `./lib/index.js`.

When I change `main` in `node_modules/react-modal/package.json` to

```
"main": "./lib/index.js",
```

the first error goes away.

I think it's indeed an issue with TypeScript.

Comment: So I opened an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12839) for this on the TypeScript repo and it turns out that the compiler will look for an index.js at the root of the npm module by default. This is counterintuitive, but if you want to use untyped imports instead of just typing in import Something from 'some-module' you need to make sure you have the location of some-module's entry point (from the package.json) and type the path to where it is within the module. In my case, I needed to type out import Modal from 'react-modal/lib'.

Comment: To me it looks like TypeScript is using `main` from `package.json` because `import ... from 'react'` works, although there is no `index.js` in react - it has `"main": "react.js"`.  The apparent issue with TypeScript is that it does not add `.js` extension when it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

try and add you tsconfig and enable and disable noImplicitAny :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../../node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  }      
}
```